# How to multiply value in previous row with a value from current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

I can't seem to find a way around the following problem. I have the following dataframe:

```
Daily Return(%)       
   -0.1                   
    0.1                   
    0.2                   
   -.01                   
    .04                   
   0.12
```

and I want to have the portfolio value calculated. The initial value of my portfolio is 500 and after the calculation I should have the following dataframe

```
Daily Return(%)     Portfolio Value     
       -0.1                   450
        0.1                   495
        0.2                   594
       -.01                   588
        .04                   611
       0.12                   684
```

The forumla of calculating the portfolio value is 500+(500x(-0.1))+(450x0.1)+(495x0.2)....

I am struggling to put the formula above into code. Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated

Comment: You want to calculate the compounded return by the formula you gave? Cause in the last sentence you said you need to calculate teh portfolio value (which is already given).
Also, you said the df has only daily return. So I am assuming portfolio values are in a seperate list?

Comment: @55abhilash, sorry my post was confusing. I edited it. I only have daily return (%) in my dataframe and I need to calculate the portfolio value. The start value of my portfolio is 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us `add` one then `cumprod`

```
df['Daily Return(%)'].add(1).cumprod()*500
0    450.000000
1    495.000000
2    594.000000
3    588.060000
4    611.582400
5    684.972288
Name: Daily, dtype: float64
df['p Value'] = df['Daily Return(%)'].add(1).cumprod()*500
```

Comment: that worked :) can you please explain what the two functions are doing?

Comment: @Nant https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html and add == +1